# iPhone application compatible with iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios-universal-app

I want to make my iPhone application visible in iTunes with the following requirement: "**compatible with iPad**". 
I want it to be working in the "**mini**" version on iPad. All related topics just answer the question "what should I do to get a universal app?", not "what should I do to get the same app (mini on iPad) on both devices?". Do I have to do anything at all? Are the following settings ok:

- Targeted device family: iPhone
- iOS deployment Target: iOS 4.0

If i set the targeted device to iPhone/iPad, xcode (3.2.5) expands all elements in the view to fit the entire screen. I don't want that. I want to be sure it installs for iPad in mini for now, the dedicated iPad version will be ready later.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your application to be in the same format (not scaled) you set the targeted device familiy to iPhone as you have done here. It is correct in other words. The iOS deployment target has nothing to do with how the app looks on the iPad. Just be sure to deploy with iOS target greater or equal to 3.2